# Debug missing messages in akka

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, akka, spray

I have the following architecture at the moment:

Load(Play app with basic interface for load tests) -> Gateway(Spray application with REST interface for incoming messages) -> Processor(akka app that works with MongoDB) -> MongoDB

Everything works fine as long as number of messages I am pushing through is low. However when I try to push 10000 events, that will eventully end up at MongoDB as documents, it stops at random places, for example on 742 message or 982 message and does nothing after.

What would be the best way to debug such situations? On the load side I am just pushing hard into the REST service:

```
for (i ← 0 until users) workerRouter ! Load(server, i)
```

and then in the workerRouter

```
WS.url(server + "/track/message").post(Json.toJson(newUser)).map { response =>
  println(response.body)
  true
}
```

On the spray side:

```
pathPrefix("track") {
  path("message") {
    post {
      entity(as[TrackObj]) { msg =>
        processors ! msg
        complete("")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On the processor side it's just basically an insert into a collection. Any suggestions on where to start from?

Update:
I tried to move the logic of creating messages to the Gatewat, did a cycle of 1 to 10000 and it works just fine. However if spray and play are involed in a pipeline it interrupts and random places. Any suggestions on how to debug in this case?

Comment: Have you tried the Typesafe Console?

Comment: No I haven't tried that yet. I figured out the problem is in Play <-> Spray communication, because if I do 100000 records on Spray side only (mean there is no HTTP communication)it works fine.

Comment: Ah, ok. Have you asked on the spray-user ml?

Comment: Can you check what your threads are doing (`jstack <pid>`) when it gets stuck? These days we get issues caused by thread-starvation almost every day. If you got something suspicious post it on the spray-user ML.

Comment: I resolved the problem, please read below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the load test app to Spray framework and now it works like a charm. So I suppose the problem was somewhere in the way that I used WS API in Play framework:

```
WS.url(server + "/track/message").post(Json.toJson(newUser)).map { response =>
  println(response.body)
  true
}
```

The problem is resovled but not solved, won't work on a solution based on Play.

Answer (score 0):

In a distributed and parallel environment it is next to impossible to create a system that work reliably. Whatever debugging method you use it will only allow you to find a few bugs that will happen during the debug session.

Once our team spent 3 months(!) while tuning an application for a robust 24/7 working. And still there were bugs. Then we applied a method of [Model checking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_checking) ([Spin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPIN_model_checker)). Within a couple of weeks we implemented a model that allowed us to get a robust application. However, **model checking** requires a bit different way of thinking and it can be difficult to start.

Comment: I do agree, however in my case all 3 layers run locally. In other words there should be no lost packages. I admit that there are memory limitations and timeouts, but knowing at least what is causing messages drop would help me. I did additional tests and figured out it is Spray<->Play communication, because if everything is done on Spray side without using HTTP pipe(means spray gateway is not used) it works fine for 100K+ records without a single error.